# Wait 5 seconds in Universal App

Tags: c#, uwp, countdown, pause

I need to make a pause in a Windows 10 UWP App.

And the only thing i want is to wait 5 seconds to do the next action.
I tried Task. Sleep but then the pressed button was frozen...

Pause should be here:

```
loading.IsActive = true;

   //int period = 5000;
   //ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer =
   //ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(period));

loading.IsActive = false;
```

How can I make a 5s pause?

Comment: You want a timer or simple `await Task.Delay(5000);` would be sufficient?

Answer (score 20):

You could use the `Task.Delay()` method:

```
loading.IsActive = true;
await Task.Delay(5000);
loading.IsActive = false;
```

When using this method your UI doesn't freeze.

**Edit**
A more readable way IMO would be to don't pass the milliseconds as parameter like in the above example. But instead pass a `TimeSpan` instance:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```